# Select data from one table which is not present in another table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, TABLE1 and TABLE2.

TABLE2 consist records from table with with some columns less. Every time the procedure is called, it checks if a combination of columns (Composite key,although not declared) is present or not.

If present the it updates one of the column else it makes a new entry.

```
desc MAIN_TBL;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| LinkID        | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| Protocol      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| SourceIP      | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| DestinationIP | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| SourcePort    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| DestPort      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| NoOfBytes     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| insertTime    | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| StartTime     | timestamp   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| EndTime       | timestamp   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| Direction     | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| Trafficbps    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| nFlows        | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| flag          | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | 0                   |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

**DATA**

```
select Protocol,SourceIP,DestinationIP,SourcePort,DestPort,NoOfBytes from MAIN_TBL;
+----------+----------+---------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| Protocol | SourceIP | DestinationIP | SourcePort | DestPort | NoOfBytes |
+----------+----------+---------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| TCP      | 1.1.1.1  | 2.2.2.2       |       1080 |      443 |     10000 |
| TCP      | 1.1.1.1  | 2.2.2.2       |       1080 |     8080 |     20000 |
| TCP      | 1.1.1.1  | 2.2.2.2       |       1090 |     8080 |     20000 |
+----------+----------+---------------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Table2:

```
desc SRCIP_TOP_TALKERS5;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| SourceIP      | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| DestinationIP | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| DestPort      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| SourcePort    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| Protocol      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| NoOfBytes     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| Time_1        | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

**Data**

```
select Protocol,SourceIP,DestinationIP,SourcePort,DestPort,NoOfBytes from SRCIP_TOP_TALKERS5;
+----------+----------+---------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| Protocol | SourceIP | DestinationIP | SourcePort | DestPort | NoOfBytes |
+----------+----------+---------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| TCP      | 1.1.1.1  | 2.2.2.2       |       1080 |      443 |     10000 |
+----------+----------+---------------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Now, My procedure first updates those entries for which the combination (SourcePort,DestPort,SourceIP,DestinationIP,Protocol) is present in **SRCIP_TOP_TALKERS5**.

Query is :

```
update SRCIP_TOP_TALKERS5 T1 INNER JOIN MAIN_TBL T2
                        on
                        T1.SourceIP = T2.SourceIP and
                        T1.DestinationIP = T2.DestinationIP and
                        T1.DestPort = T2.DestPort and
                        T1.SourcePort = T2.SourcePort and
                        T1.Protocol = T2.Protocol
                        set T1.NoOfBytes=T1.NoOfBytes+T2.NoOfBytes;
```

**After this, I want the remaining rows to be inserted for which there was no match found.
If you consider my existing data (shown above), I should get 2 rows as output from MAIN_TBL for which the combination on 5 tuples are not present in SRCIP_TOP_TALKERS5**

Comment: Guys, let me know if some information is needed..

Answer (score 0):

You can do a RIGHT JOIN.

```
UPDATE SRCIP_TOP_TALKERS5 T1
RIGHT JOIN MAIN_TBL T2 ON T1.SourceIP = T2.SourceIP
AND T1.DestinationIP = T2.DestinationIP
AND T1.DestPort = T2.DestPort
AND T1.SourcePort = T2.SourcePort
AND T1.Protocol = T2.Protocol
set T1.NoOfBytes= COALESCE(T1.NoOfBytes,0) + T2.NoOfBytes;
```

Do COALESCE for T2 if T1 is not subset of T2.Let me know, if this works for you.

Comment: hi Raghav, FULL OUTER JOIN is not supported in mysql.. I tried you query by replacing "FULL OUTER JOIN" with only "JOIN", it behaves similar to the query I have given above. (It updates the NoOfBytes of existing records). My actual query was to find records which are not present in SRCIP_TOP_TALKERS5 table.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by referring some other link on SO.

I need to do a left join and put a null check (Important here is pull all the columns from both tables in select)

```
select T1.NoOfBytes as NoOfBytes,T1.Protocol as Protocol,T1.SourcePort as SourcePort,T1.SourceIP as SourceIP,
                    T1.DestinationIP as DestinationIP,T1.DestPort as DestPort,
                    T2.Protocol as Proto,T2.SourcePort as srcPrt,T2.SourceIP as SrcIP,T2.DestinationIP as DestIP,T2.DestPort as DstPrt
                    from MAIN_TBL T1 left join SRCIP_TOP_TALKERS5 T2
                    on T1.SourceIP = T2.SourceIP and
                            T1.DestinationIP = T2.DestinationIP and
                            T1.DestPort = T2.DestPort and
                            T1.SourcePort = T2.SourcePort and
                            T1.Protocol = T2.Protocol
                    where T2.SourcePort is null
```